# Making an image stay in the centre of section

Tags: css

I have made a section, split in to two columns. One is writing, one is a picture.
How do I make the picture align itself in the centre of the text.

As in the height of the image will be aligned with the height of the text.

```css
.intro {
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.intro section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

.intro img {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='intro'>
  <section>
    <h2 class='intro-para'> I have been a science and maths tutor for the past three years and have tutored students of all abilites. I am very enthusastic about STEM and look to pass on some of that interest to my students. I offer one free session to each student so please
      don't hesitate to get in contact. </h2>
  </section>
  <img class='ed' src=".//images/ed.jpeg">
</div>
```

- I have tried using align items center
- I have tried using justify content

But I could be using these wrong!

Comment: "I have tried" so show what you tried, and explain how they didn't work.

Comment: This code isn't complete. You should paste the whole code. Like </section> is separated etc.

Answer (score 0):

`align-items` and `justify-content` are properties you can use when using `flexbox` to align content.

Make sure the parent of the image has `display: flex` as well in order to use them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your two columns with another div and give it

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

To align two section centered you can use

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

html:

```
<section>
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic odit rerum, eveniet magnam repellendus iusto. Praesentium incidunt eos nulla molestias laudantium, quo earum, ea quidem, officiis est voluptatibus perspiciatis facere.</p>
</section>
```

css:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section{
  font-size: 0;
}

p, img{
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fueoyz1b/39/

Another way of doing it might be by using flexbox as suggested in other answers.